# How to find the no of mondays, tuesdays, wednesdays, thursdays and fridays in a month from a given date

Tags: apex, formula

I am trying to get the no of mondays, tuesdays, wednesdays, thursdays and fridays in a month from a given date to end of month and from given date to beginning of the month in two formula fields

Lets say if the date is 9/15/2018, then we have Mon = 2, tue=2,wed=3,thu=2,fri=2, Sat=3,Sun=3

I am ok if its a formula or even an apex. Any pointers would be of great help

Update : Based on @cropredy reference [SO Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40077783/excel-calculate-remaining-mondays-in-each-month)  i built this formula

(End_of_Month__c -TODAY()+WEEKDAY(TODAY())-1)/7

But not sure where i need to specify if its a monday/tue.. etc

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: well, formulas are more or less like Excel functions so there's this [stackoverflow item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40077783/excel-calculate-remaining-mondays-in-each-month) that you could adapt - you would need to implement a formula that returned what Excel does OOTB for EOMONTH

Comment: @cropredy thanks for the pointer. I cant seem to figure out where we are saying that its a monday or tue

Comment: What's the output you're looking for? Is it really the string, "Mon = 2, Tue=2, ...," or are the numbers going to be used in some other way?

Comment: What I am looking for is a number which tells the no if Mondays or no of Tuesdays left in the month. I would create a new field for each day

Comment: @ShaneSteinfeld i would be  using this number for few other complex  business requirements